# Не работает удаление ячейки по свайпу

Tags: swift, xcode

Суть такая, прохожу учебный материал и приложение разрастается. А проблема следующая, после добавление логики по сортировки по имени и дате, перестал работать свайп удаление ячейки, при попытки свайпнуть открывается более детальная информация о ячейки. Подскажите кто сталкивался с такой проблемой

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
   
    let deliteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Удалить") { (_, _, _) in
        
        StoregeMagager.deliteObject(place)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        
    }
    
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deliteAction])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант могу посоветовать удалить данные из массива информации которую использует список и потом перезагрузить его (пример):

```
self.messagesArray.remove(at: self.selectedIndex.section)
mList.reloadData()
```

так же насколько я знаю в вашем способе удаления, нужно сначала запускать обновление виджета - удалять ячейку - останавливать обновление виджета:

```
self.catNames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Если у вас при попытке свайпа открывается то что должно открываться при нажатии (если я правильно понял, то имеет смысл пересмотреть логику, возможно где-то не подключен метод свайпа после фильтрации)

Comment: Тут все немного усугубляется тем что весь массив находиться в mongo db, но ваш вариант сегодня попробую если он отработает

Comment: вам же по логике нужно предварительно как-то данные вытащить и потом загрузить в список

Comment: Как я понимаю, если это был обычный массив, то можно было временно хранить в переменной а вот как быть с бд? У меня там реализует записать и удаления. Поправьте если я не прав

Comment: Да все верно, но я так думаю можно выгружать из бд для заполнения списка, это мне кажется немного более мобильное, чем ждать пока обновится бд, но с другой стороны нужно ловить апдейты бд чтобы обновить все локально

Comment: Спасибо. Сегодня вечером попробую.

Comment: Удачи :) Если что пишите, будем разбираться :D

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошо 

Comment: я тут поставил на телефон там просто не работает свай. Кстати ставлю приложение без сертификата разработчика на 14.0.1. у них какой то баг